# TYPO3-NEOS how to create page URL using german special characters

Tags: url, typo3, neoscms

Is it possible to create a new page using german special character in a url path (e.g `example.com/prüfung.html`).

The `ü` character can't pass validation, and if i try to change the validation rules so it can pass the validation, the page can't be accessed neither via backend nor frontend.

is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think currently we do not allow that. I can open a feature request and have a look at it. Would you explain why you need that? I mean is it better for SEO? Because actually this URL will be impossible to enter for some people not using a German keyboard.